# YOLO Pre-trained weights using Open Images Dataset V4

Tags: keras, yolo

I want to use an object detection model for some use case.

I started with the YOLOv3, because I need to be able to perform detection on multiple images in less than few seconds (Even if it is not for real-time / video).

So, I successfully loaded and generated predictions using a [keras model with pretrained weights](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3).

The problem is that the pre-trained weights for this model have been generated with the COCO dataset, which contains very few classes (80).

What really surprises me is that all the pre-trained weights I can found for this type of algorithms use the COCO dataset, and none of them use the [Open Images Dataset V4](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/download.html) (which contains 600 classes).

Is there a reason for that ? And if there is not, is there a place where I can find such pre-trained weights ?

Answer (score 1):

Darknet has a yolo implementation using Open Images check [this page](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) (scroll down up to the end, just before the citation)

You can simply use
wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3-openimages.weights

Comment: I tried to use these weights, but it look like there is only few classes.
When I tried to do a detection with a turtle image, it is pretty confident that it is a bird (like with the weights trained with COCO, which have not been trained to recognize turtles), and with a pizza picture it give no prediction at all (with the weights trained with COCO the prediction is good).

Comment: Try retraining the last layer

Comment: How to pass labels to train last layer? model has to predict boundary boxes right?

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/training-yolov3-deep-learning-based-custom-object-detector/ check this tutorial